# What's a word for lack of confidence?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm trying to find a word that describes a lack of confidence. Something that gives a sense of worthlessness maybe. I've dried looking up in Thesarus.com for similarities to lack of confidence and antonyms to self-worth, but with no luck. Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: First option: *diffidence*; alternate, *inadequacy*? However, your context seems a bit different and as you suggested,  *a sense of worthlessness* seems very appropriate.

Comment: i needed a single word. diffidence was good

Comment: Floccinaucinihilipilification will give you a sense of worthlessness.

Comment: Try timid: Lacking in courage or confidence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to OED:

> **diffident**: modest or shy because of a lack of self-confidence: *a diffident youth.*

Another word as @Jim suggested would be *timid*.

> **timid**: showing a lack of courage or confidence; easily frightened: *I was too timid to ask for what I wanted.*

Answer (score 8):

"Insecurity" would be a good one.  To have insecurity is to have lack of self-confidence, lack of self-worth.  Insecure.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

> 1. *Timid*: Showing fear and lack of confidence
> 2. *Diffident*: Lacking self-confidence. E.g: *stood in the doorway diffident and abashed*
> 3. *Fainthearted*: Lacking conviction or boldness or courage.

Comment: Where are the definitions taken from? Always indicate your sources. Always. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think *[wavering](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wavering)* (“Fluctuating; being in doubt; undetermined; indecisive; uncertain; unsteady”),  *[faltering](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/faltering)* (To “be unsure or weak” or “Move hesitatingly, as if about to give way”, etc.), and *[irresolute](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/irresolute#Adjective)* (“Undecided or unsure how to act” or “Indecisive or lacking in resolution”) might serve.

Also consider *[unsure](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unsure#Adjective)*, *[doubting](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doubting)* or *doubtful*, *[iffy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iffy)*, *[chancy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chancy)*, and *[dicey](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dicey#English)* (“Of uncertain, risky outcome” or “Of doubtful or uncertain efficacy, provenance, etc.; dodgy”).